# Get rid of vertical space between items in a ListView

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` that looks like this:

[image: ListView with vertical space between items.]

I am trying to remove the space between the items.

Setting the `Margin` and `Padding` of the `ItemTemplate` to zero is not working.

Setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, the `ItemContainerStyle` must have a template with a `ListViewItemPresenter` where the `ContentMargin` is set to 0. As well as the `Margin` of the `ItemContainerStyle` must be 0.

ListView:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomItemContainerStyle}">
<ListView/>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <!-- The following two styles fixes the issue of items not expanding 100%. -->
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <!-- Margin must be zero to get rid of the space between items. Default is 1.-->
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <!-- ListViewItem styles and templates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709921.aspx -->
    <!-- ContentMargin must be zero to get rid of the vertical space between items. Defaults is 4. -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter
                    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                    CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}"
                    CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}"
                    CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}"
                    DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                    FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}"
                    PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
                    SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"
                    DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                    DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                    ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    PointerOverBackgroundMargin="0"
                    ContentMargin="4" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Final screenshot:

[image: ListView without vertical space between items.]